# how to make divs bottom pointy like in this image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my background image be shaped like the image attached below.

html:

```
<div id="hero-banner">

</div>
```

scss:

```
div#hero-banner {
    margin-top: -60px;
    max-height: 600px;
    height: 60vh;
    min-width: 100%;
    background: url('http://finedininglovers.cdn.crosscast-system.com/ImageAlbum/6830/original_001.jpg') no-repeat, linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
    background: url('http://finedininglovers.cdn.crosscast-system.com/ImageAlbum/6830/original_001.jpg') no-repeat, webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
    background: url('http://finedininglovers.cdn.crosscast-system.com/ImageAlbum/6830/original_001.jpg') no-repeat, moz-linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
    background-blend-mode: overlay;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Like this picture below

[image]

Comment: Rather than the professional solutions, using a `png` with transparent cut parts is an easy way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) to clip an element to the desired shape. [This tool](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) is amazing to fiddle around to get the exact shape you want.

```css
div#hero-banner {
  margin-top: -60px;
  max-height: 600px;
  height: 60vh;
  min-width: 100%;
  background: url('http://finedininglovers.cdn.crosscast-system.com/ImageAlbum/6830/original_001.jpg') no-repeat, linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
  background: url('http://finedininglovers.cdn.crosscast-system.com/ImageAlbum/6830/original_001.jpg') no-repeat, webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
  background: url('http://finedininglovers.cdn.crosscast-system.com/ImageAlbum/6830/original_001.jpg') no-repeat, moz-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
  background-blend-mode: overlay;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 90%, 18% 100%, 0 90%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 90%, 18% 100%, 0 90%);
}
```

```html
<div id="hero-banner">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I'll mark this as the answer once it will let me. :)